# Write number with + before it if it is positive

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I need to write numbers to the console with their signs. I mean if the number that I want to write is negative, there is no problem because the number will have the minus before it, but if it is positive, it will not appear like "+some_value", it will appear like "some_walue". I want the sign to be allways visible, and I'm wondering if it is a function which do this easyer.
Sorry for my english...

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

This is simple with integer.ToString.

```
Dim i as Integer ="111"

Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("+#;-#;0"))
'outputs +111
i ="-111"
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("+#;-#;0"))
'outputs -111
i ="0"
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("+#;-#;0"))
'outputs 0
```

This will output +MyNumber, -MyNumber and zero as 0 without any sign

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you want

```
Console.WriteLine(IIf(myNumber > 0 ,"+","").ToString + myNumber.ToString)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following for the console write:

```
   if number > 0 Then
      Console.WriteLine("+{0}", number)
   Else
      Console.WriteLine(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple application, and I don't really know what you have tried, but this here works:

```
int number = 9123;
Console.Write("+" + number);
Console.ReadLine();
```

You would need to check if it was a positive number, or negative, but this works.

EDIT: Here is how to check if it is positive, or negative:

```
        if (number > 0)
        {
            Console.Write("+" + number);
        }
        else if (number == 0)
        {
            Console.Write(number);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("-" + number);
        }
```